# Top nav disappears in safari, shows in IE, Mozilla

Tags: html, web, css

here's the link http://www.alegup.net.....thank you ....wish I didn't have to ask.

Answer (score 0):

You've got unmatched li and div tags in your navigation. Safari will then ignore them.